# Redux Toolkit + Express set initial state from window object

Tags: reactjs, express, react-redux, redux-toolkit

New to SSR/node.js and redux toolkit.

I am trying to figure out how to set the initial state of the store on the client side with the store coming from server side.

The store is a user session (name, email, etc.) that is being injected via window object. I can verify that it is being passed to the client because previously it has been using just redux. Looking to take full advantage and wanted to convert to redux-toolkit.

Wondering if `preloadedState` is the way to go here?

```
const initialState = window.redux_store;

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {},
  preloadedSate: initialState
});
```

Or am I missing something?

TIA!

Comment: `preloadedState` is the way to go. But, since its data you receive from server, is `window.redux_store` already defined when you use it?

Comment: Thank you! And yes, window.redux_store is already defined.

Comment: Did you solved this problem? I got the same problem `window is not defined` and I didn't find anwser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add that data in serverside in template using

```
html_template""
<script>
window.redux_store = JSON.stringify(yourData)
</script>
""
```

**But Be carefull!!**
It might cause XSS attack to avoid that (if it's not real project ignore that part) you have to use javascript serialize package